# Content Download time is high even more than HTTP request itself

Tags: service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I am using workbox and the strategy is stalewhilerevalidate for /xyz API.

1. Response via service worker from cache. total time taken: **741ms**

[image]

2. Fetch call from service worker via workbox to server. total time taken **131ms**

[image]

Code snippet looks like following with match callback and match callback is just having logic of url matching.

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(isBaseAPI,
workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate());
```

Am I missing anything? Please let me know